# Browser not load 404 page, but I already redirect in .htaccess

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I just made error404 page, but browser not load every code, it just load 404 error's title

I have made .htaccess and 404 page on my localhost
here is the snippets

```
DirectoryIndex  index.html
ErrorDocument 404 error404.html
```

But now, if I try to type localhost/notanypage,
in the browser shown a text: error404.html

Comment: That probably means the server did not find the file, and therefor just outputs the "argument" as static text then. What happens when you try using a path beginning with a slash, relative to the document root? (So `ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html` in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe mentioned in comments, when specifying a custom error document, the *document* argument used with the `ErrorDocument` directive takes is root-relative URL-path and must start with a slash. Otherwise it will be treated as a "string" and output as plain text.

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
```

Or, a plain string:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "Sorry, I could not find that file!"
```

(Enclosing the *string* in double quotes is only necessary if it contains *spaces*.)

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument